# Simple JSON parse example wanted in VB.Net

Tags: json.net

I'm doing my first steps with Newtonsoft Json parser, but there are very fex examples on VB.net apperently. I just want to parse a string, and then I want to be able to loop throught the different list

This is my code :

```
Dim JSON As String
Dim values As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
JSON = "{'mailadresses': {    'List1':{'Stefaan Somers': 'JoskeVermeulen@gmail.com',          'Markske': 'mdtre@gmail.com'       }, 'List2':{'Stefaan XSomers': 'Test@gmail.com',         'xMarkske': 'mdrmdtre@gmail.com'       }}"
values = JObject.Parse(JSON)
```

It directly gives me the error when running :
Unexpected end of content while loading JObject. Path 'mailadresses', line 1, position 221.

Any idea also on how to loop through the different elements. I don't want to cast to a custom class, as described in many samples

Answer (score 0):

Your json isnt valid according to jsonlint.

try this instead:

```
{
    "mailadresses": {
        "List1": {
            "StefaanSomers": "JoskeVermeulen@gmail.com",
            "Markske": "mdtre@gmail.com"
        },
        "List2": {
            "StefaanXSomers": "Test@gmail.com",
            "xMarkske": "mdrmdtre@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```